# WildFly/JBoss server group deployment understanding

Tags: domain-controller, jboss

According to JBoss documentation:

> In managed domain deployments are associated with a server group.
>   Deployments will be provided to any server that belongs to a
>   particular group.

...the multiple servers in common server group become the single one virtually.

But how does JBoss choose the target actual server for deployment?

For example, i have two different vps servers with JBoss running, which are combined to the single main-server-group. Then which vps server will actually host the application by following command?

> [domain@localhost:9999 /] deploy ~/Desktop/test-application.war
>   --server-group=main-server-group 'test-application.war' deployed successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not pick a server but deploys the application to all of the servers in the specified group.

The documentation should probably state that

> Deployments will be provided to **all** servers that belong to a
>   particular group